# How triggre a popup by onload function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am trying to set a popup in my site and I got a example. The popup file by click function but I want to fire that popup on page load. Here is the popup function

HTML :

```
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Popup </a>

<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
<div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>Wow! This is Awesome! (Popup #1)</h2>
    <p>Popup text </p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Can any one help me please .....

Comment: Currently you're triggering that by clicking on something. What do you think happens if you move that code *outside* of the click handler?

Comment: I want to fire the popup on page load

Comment: You didn't even address what I said.

Comment: The code will execute without click

Comment: Yes. And... assuming you put that code at the *bottom* of the page, *when* does that code execute?

Comment: After load the page

Comment: You've got it. That's one solution. The answer by @user1289451 is better because then you don't have to load your script at the bottom of the page or worry about it if someone else doesn't load it correctly.

Comment: I tried it but my popup didnt fire

Answer (score 1):

https://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
});
```

**Edit:** removed `e.preventDefault();`

**Edit:** fixing overlooked issues that cause the above code to not work.

You could simply give your div an id of popup-1 and access it directly.

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#popup-1').fadeIn(350);
});
```

Comment: Define not working. The pop up doesn't come up? You get an error?

Comment: You have to add jQuery

Comment: @DropShadow Come on, they aren't just handing you the solution on a silver platter. Put in a little bit of thinking for yourself.

Comment: You don't need the `e.preventDefault()`. That's just for handling things like click events. I think in this case it will actually cause an error.

Comment: You are right Mike. I tested it in a fiddle and it did indeed cause an error. Will remove.

Comment: The other thing is this line `var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');`. Since `this` isn't going to be a clicked on element, they need to manually set that to something like `popup-1` or find that value in the DOM somewhere.

Comment: @DropShadow see my second edit and let me know if that helps at all

Answer (score -1):

You can create a modal & on document ready you can open it

```
    <div class="modal fade in" id="mydiv" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  style="display: block; aria-hidden="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog">            
                <div class="modal-content"> 
                    <div class="modal-header">
                       <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
                          <div class="popup-inner">
                          <h2>Wow! This is Awesome! (Popup #1)</h2>
                          <p>Popup text </p>
                          <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
                          <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    $(document).ready(function(e)  {
       $("#mydiv").modal('show');
    });
```

as well as button click

```
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mydiv">Popup </a>
```

I didn't see any wrong code here but why clicked not useful.